# String index out of range (different in length error)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, matching

The problem is that the number of strings in list l1 is longer than the number of str in your_name_no, so when I try to match the index with the characters, it matches with an error due to length difference, which I tried to exclude using the if function, but didn't work.

[image: An image of my code]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: Change `<=` to `<`. Indexes start at `0` and end at `len(your_name)-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because the `len` of a list, or a string, counts beginning from 1, and not 0, opposite to how indexes work. For instance:

```
a = 'hello'
print(len(a))
Output:
5
```

However, if you were to iterate over an index of 5 values, you would get index error because `a[5]` doesn't exist, there's no fifth element in that string (since it begins in 0 and goes up to 4).

You can solve this by either changing the `<=` to `<` as @Barmar suggested, or adding a `-1` when applying the criteria in the for loop:

```
for r in range(0,len(l1)):
  if r < len(your_name):
     print(r, your_name[r]
```

Or:

```
for r in range(0,len(l1)):
   if r <= (len(your_name)-1):
     print(r, your_name[r]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I am in still in the beginning for learning python, but that helped

Answer (score 0):

you should set the if condition like this:

```py
if r < len(your_name)
```

because the last index is lower than the length of the list by 1, since lists start with index 0.

Comment: Thanks so much, I just realized that